# Is it possible to ask a user arbitrary, changing questions at checkout with Craft Commerce?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, user-interface

Craft Commerce allows us to have one set of custom Order Fields associated with a checkout process. I have a situation where we are selling tickets to a yearly event and I need to ask two questions of each registrant that change from year to year. For this example, I'll present the following two questions, but it's possible that the number of questions and type of question changes from year to year:

```
Year 1:
- Will you attend the opening reception on Friday?
- Will you attend the lunch reception on Saturday?

Year 2:
- Will you attend the opening reception on Thursday?
- Will you attend the lunch reception on Friday?
```

It seems custom Order Fields will not easily solve this use case with an ideal workflow for the content admin for two reasons:

1. The questions need to change from year to year, which would require a developer update the Order Fields layout
2. Even if a developer did go in and change the questions to be the ones relevant to the year, they'd be breaking the data model of the previous year rendering past data inaccurate and useless (if someone wished to query it for whatever reason)

The ideal solution would allow an admin to:

- Create a product for a new year
- Customize the arbitrary questions they need to ask each user who checks out (The questions for the Order would ideally be associated with the Product Field Layout, not the Order Field Layout)
- Have the option to query accurate data (questions and responses) for all customers of a product for a specific year

Before I go down the road of custom development, are there any supported or existing options that address the use case described above?

Comment: Fun question... I'm not very clever, but I can't think of a way to do it without custom plugin development.